# Python 3 How to make Event Filter via createFilter web3.py v4.2.1

Tags: solidity, python, web3.py, filters

According to the Web3.py Documentation: http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html

```
event_filter = contract.events.myEvent.createFilter(fromBlock='latest', {'filter': {'arg1':10}})

                                                              ^
```

Then I got: "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument"

Then I removed "fromBlock='lastest',"

```
event_filter = contract.events.myEvent.createFilter({'filter': {'arg1':10}})
```

Then I got: "TypeError: createFilter() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Ok... then I Googled that...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given

let's try: my_new_object = cInst.events()

Then I got "TypeError: 'ContractEvents' object is not callable"

Does this web3.py Documentation work at all??? I am so disappointed... :(

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following method in web3py to get events:

```
myfilter = mycontract.eventFilter('EventName', {'fromBlock': 0,'toBlock': 'latest'});
eventlist = myfilter.get_all_entries()
```

`eventlist` will be a list of dictionaries containing the parameters of each event that had happened.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow. Thank you Jaime. However I got this: "requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='room2.abc.com', port=8545): Read timed out. (read timeout=10) ". Could you suggest something? Thank you!

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your node connection, are you running your own node?, be sure that you are actually connected to the network, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Jaime, you are absolutely correct. The node was down... Thank you!

Comment: Jaime, I got it: event_list[idx].args.eventArgument1 !!! THANK YOU!

Comment: How could I also add `filter` @Jaime ?

Comment: what do you mean by "add filter"

Comment: Is that normal I get an empty list returning an event that was obliviously created during truffle test unit (let's say "Deposit")? Because I'm connecting on ganache-cli, load the abi correctly, but events are empty and I can't use infura since no support of event