# Python Web3 Contract Filtering

Tags: web3.py, python

I am trying to filter out transactions from BSC and read their input data (specifically borrows from venus), however I am having trouble getting my event filter to work properly.

I have already tried to search around for an answer, and found [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/49694/66712) but it doesn't seem to help me as there is no longer a `contract.eventFilter()` function.

Here is my code:

```py
import json
from web3 import Web3
from time import sleep

abi = json.load(open('abi.json', 'r'))
# I got the abi from https://bscscan.com/address/0xcf6bb5389c92bdda8a3747ddb454cb7a64626c63#code

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"))

contract = w3.eth.contract(address="0xd4CB328A82bDf5f03eB737f37Fa6B370aef3e888", abi=abi)

transfer_filter = contract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock="0x0", argument_filters={'from': '0xd4CB328A82bDf5f03eB737f37Fa6B370aef3e888'})

while True:
  print(transfer_filter.get_new_entries())
  sleep(2)
```

I'm not really too sure where I am going wrong, as I don't know if I have the right `from` address for `transfer_filter` as the only output I am getting is `[]`.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

specify addresses in lowercase in `argument_filters`.

```py
argument_filters={'from': '0xd4CB328A82bDf5f03eB737f37Fa6B370aef3e888'.lower()}
```